# 2 EventHandlers calling the same Function

Tags: c#, eventhandler

If I have 2 Events on my application,Let's say Event1 and Event2, that are independent and can be invoked randomly by other factors.

In their EventHandlers I am calling a function.

```
 void OnEvent1(EventArgs e)
{
    A();
}

 void OnEvent2(EventArgs e)
{
   A();
}

void A(){

// logic

}
```

If one of the events arrived while A() is still executing from the previous event, Does it wait for A logic to be executed or it interrupts A logic and might cause race condition?

Comment: If the callbacks are called from different threads you can have a race condition

Comment: Events aren't magic, they are invoked by the caller on the same thread. Events have nothing to do with thread-safety. If they are invoked from different threads, you'll have to do some synchronization. So, know where they events are invoked from.

Comment: Even if the events are raised on the same thread, for example in a UI application, reentrancy is a common source of bugs, but does not involve a race condition.

Comment: @UnholySheep Would a _lock on the function A() prevent this race condition? In a sense where the latter callback waits for the previous one to be done from the executing?

Comment: In many cases using a `lock` statement is the right choice to prevent concurrent access to a shared resource, yes

Comment: @MikeZboray Is that race condition prevented by the UI thread being blocked by the function A()? I tried to have a for loop in the function A() and it seems the loop gets fully executed then the next loop start even though the 2 event handlers were executed.

Comment: @Muhannad There's not a race condition because there is only 1 thread.

Comment: @MikeZboray that makes sense. Is it possible to prevent reentrancy  in this case can have A() fully executed before the next run from an event handler?

Comment: Is `A` triggering one of the events, and so being called again while already executing?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson No A() is doing its own logic. however; every time A is called from an event handler it will check for a condition. I was worried that this condition would be reported incorrectly due to the function being called twice before it's done executing!

Answer (score 1):

For an immediate answer, you can use lock: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Ultimately this will 'lock' an object and won't allow another thread to lock/use the same object until the original lock has been released. The only thing you'd want to look out for is a deadlock condition - where the two threads are waiting for something to happen before it finishes running 'A()'. Make sense?

```
 private readonly object taskLock = new object();

 void OnEvent1(EventArgs e)
 {
     lock (taskLock)
     {
        A();
     }
 }

 void OnEvent2(EventArgs e)
 {
     lock (taskLock)
     {
        A();
     }
 }

 void A()
 {
    // logic
 }
```

I'll use locks on data table or list objects when i have a background worker / alternative thread running a task (you can lock other objects, you don't HAVE to make a "taskLock".

Comment: I am sorry a have a stupid question, but does the lock work on the same locking thread? By this I mean if a Thread X locked code and X tried to run the same code would it go through or it will wait for the lock to be released then execute?

Comment: Not a stupid question! Yes, if Thread X is using the code and attempts to re-lock it, it's going to "Get in line" until the first request is finished :)